# Chrome device inspect cannot find Ionic Application

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome

I'm running debug my `Ionic` application with `cordova run android` and trying debug with `chrome://inspect`, it's found my device and list websites opened in my cellphone, but is not finding my Ionic application.

How to can I detect my Ionic application in my `Chrome`?

Following my `cordova plugin list`:

```
cordova-admobsdk 1.0.4 "Google Mobile Ads SDK for Cordova"
cordova-plugin-admob 3.2.4 "Cordova-Phonegap AdMob Plugin"
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.25.0 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.1 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
```

Device information:

- Device: ASUS_T00F (Zenfone 1)
- Android version: 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need Android >= 4.4.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) The Chrome docs about it. Remember that Cordova use a WebView to show your app, and if you want to debbug an InApp WebViews you need Android 4.4 or high

Comment: I think so, I see this details now too, I'm trying using another way to prove this

Comment: @Lai32290 I just update the answer, in fact you need Android >= 4.4

Comment: I think android version is the problem, I'm debugging with `weinre` now, and is working.

Comment: Yes, @Lai32290 Android version is the main point in this, since version 4.0 you can inspect webs, but just from Android 4.4 and above you can inspect InApp WebViews (And that is Cordova, a WebView inside an App)

Answer (score 1):

Another point to note - in order for Chrome to detect in app 'WebView' of your Cordova application, your Cordova application must be of 'debug' version obtained from Cordova build. If your Cordova application is of 'release' version, Chrome will not be able to detect the 'WebView'.